# Submit 3 different values and names all in one form with link

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with 3 different submit button with different values and names. How do i change these submit buttons into links? Using hidden input? But with conditions.

```
<form name="nosearch" action="access_search.asp" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="search">
<input type="submit" name="btnListUS" value="list-us">
<input type="submit" name="btnListCA" value="list-ca">
</form>
```

I want each input to be something like `<a href="" onclick="nosearch.submit....>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need them to look like links, you don't need to use the *a* tag, simply change the look of the buttons.

See here: [How to make a submit button display as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)