# How to make a submit button of form in HTML looks like a link?

Tags: html

I use `<input type="submit" value="insert"/>` as a button in html. But how can I make this button look like a link (word with underline) but still works like a button (submit the form)?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yet?

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a submit button display as a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/52yzG/)**</kbd>

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

or

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

input[type="submit"] {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the CSS for it. You can just reference it using button.id or button#class and use regular CSS to make it look however you want with the CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged this question as duplicate from this: [Stackoverflow: how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="submitLink" value="Submit">
```

CSS:

```
.submitLink {
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: underline;
border: none;
color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/Yx6kS/)

Snagged from: [How to make a submit button like a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)

Comment: You should re-post answer from duplicate questions. You should flag the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: how do you flag for duplicate? I was looking for that..maybe i just missed it?

Comment: Nevermind. You don't enough rep yet (15). Let me go take care of that for you.

Comment: You should see the flag link now under the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I flagged it for duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Css:
    Input[type=submit]{
    Text-decoration:underline;
    Border:none;
    Background:none;
    Display:inline;
    Cursor:pointer;
    }