# how do i use hyperlink to java form with name in it

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

I have a button "view" in which it will go to my controller and it will do something

```
<button type="Submit" name="View" form="submitForm" value="view"/>
```

this will run the submitForm and will go to my controller and then do some action

in the controller:

I have something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/runForm", method =     RequestMethod.POST, params = "View")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView viewMultipleFileHandler(
         //Do some stuff
    }
```

how do i convert the button to hyperlink like

```
<a href="something">Click here</a>
```

whereby this link will link to my form with the value "View"

Answer (score 0):

Basically i found an alternative:

[How to make a submit button display as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)

Change a button look like a link instead :)