# Converting an image input type to text link?

Tags: php, html

I have an image on a page that updates the quantities of items in a user's shopping cart. If they have selected a quantity of 1 and then change the quantity to 2, this button updates the cart contents.

The problem is that this button needs to be converted to a text link instead. I've tried all of the ways I would normally do this but its not working out.

```
<input type="image" src="%%GLOBAL_IMG_PATH%%/%%GLOBAL_SiteColor%%/UpdateButton.gif" alt="%%LNG_UpdateButton%%" />
```

Any suggestions that would help me convert this button to a simple text link would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a submit button display as a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628958/how-to-make-a-submit-button-display-as-a-link)

Comment: Change to input type="submit" and style it with CSS

Comment: Do you have any event handlers for the image ?. If so then you need to attach those event handlers to the text link